# How can I query data according to specific time periods in mongoDb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My example blog document:
[image: My MongoDB Data]

I have been trying to fetch data according to a specific time period (a particular month) but the data returned is an empty array.

```js
router.get("/:year/:month/all", async (req, res) => {
  let { year, month } = req.params;
  const blogs = await Blog.find({
    published: {
      $gte: new Date(+year, +month, 31),
      $lte: new Date(+year, +month, 0),
    },
  });
  if(!blogs || blogs.length == 0) {
    return res.json({
      success: false,
      message: "No blogs Found!"
    })
  }
  res.json({
    success: true,
    message: "Blogs Found",
    blogs,
  });
});
```

Comment: try `await Blog.find({ 
  published: {
        $gte: new Date(new Date(+year, +month).setHours(00, 00, 00))
        $lt: new Date(new Date(+year, +month).setHours(23, 59, 59))
         }
  });`

Comment: Swap `$gte` and `$lte` values.

Comment: That query has `$gte` and `$lte` reversed.  As written it is looking for a date that is both before the first of the month, and after the 31st, so nothing can match.

Answer (score 0):

When someone has to work with date/time arithmetic then I always recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library.

Would be this

```
published: {
  $gte: moment().startOf('month').toDate,
  $lte: moment().endOf('month').toDate
}
```